# Gradient of $X \mapsto \mbox{tr} \left(BXCX^TB^TBXCX^TB^T\right)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, scalar-fields

Let us assume that

\begin{equation}
f(X)=\mbox{tr}\left(XCX^TXCX^T\right),
\end{equation}

in which $C\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$ is a symmetric matrix, and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{r'\times r}$. From the Page 13 of the book [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), we know that

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}=4CXX^TCX.
\end{equation}

Now, let us consider the following function:

\begin{equation}
g(X)=\mbox{tr}\left(BXCX^TB^TBXCX^TB^T\right),
\end{equation}

where $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times r'}$. What is the derivative of $g$ with respect to $X$ (i.e., $\frac{\partial g}{\partial X}$)?

Comment: Here is a matrix derivation method by Taylor formula. For example, if $g(X)=X^2$, then $g(X+Y)=X^2+XY+YX+Y^2=g(X)+\langle X+X^t,Y\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\langle Y^t,Y\rangle.$ Thus $\frac{\partial g(X)}{\partial X}=X+X^t.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's yet another way. Define the derivative $Df(X)$ of $f$ at $X$ as the linear map such that for any matrix $H$ proportional to some $h$ you have
$$f(X+H)=f(X)+Df(X)(H)+O(h^2)$$
In particular, you can calculate $Df(X)(H)$ as
$$Df(X)(H)=f(X+H)-f(X)$$
where you can suppose that $H$ is proportional to a symbol $h$ such that $h^2=0$.
Hence $D$ satisfies
$$\begin{align}
D(f\circ g)(X)(H)
&=f(g(X+H))-f(g(X)) \\
&=f(g(X)+Dg(X)(H))-f(g(X))\\
&=f(g(X))+Df(g(X))(Dg(X)(H))-f(g(X))\\
&=[Df(g(X))\circ Dg(X)](H)
\end{align}$$
so that
$$D(f\circ g)(X)=Df(g(X))\circ Dg(X)$$

Now your function $g$ can be written as
$$g(X)=v(u(z(X)))$$
where
$$z(X)=BX$$
$$u(Y)=YCY^T$$
$$v(W)=W:W^T$$
and $A:B=\mathrm{tr}(A^TB)=\mathrm{tr}(AB^T)$ satisfies $A:B=B:A=B^T:A^T$ as in greg's answer.
So it suffices to calculate $Dz(X)$, $Du(Y)$ and $Dv(W)$.
Again, assuming $H$ is proportional to a symbol $h$ where $h^2=0$, we have
$$Dz(X)(H)=z(X+H)-z(X)=B(X+H)-BX=BH$$
$$\begin{align}
Du(Y)(H)
&=u(Y+H)-u(Y) \\
&= (Y+H)C(Y+H)^T - YCY^T \\
&= YCH^T + HCY^T \\
&= 2YCH^T
\end{align}$$
since $C=C^T$. Also
$$\begin{align}
Dv(W)(H)
&= v(W+H)-v(Y) \\
&= (W+H):(W+H)^T - W:W^T \\
&= W:H^T + H:W^T \\
&= 2W:H^T
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
Dg(X)(H)
&= D(v\circ u\circ z)(X)(H) \\
&= [Dv(u(z(X))) \circ D(u\circ z)(X)](H) \\
&= [Dv(u(z(X))) \circ Du(z(X)) \circ Dz(X)](H) \\
&= [Dv(u(z(X))) \circ Du(z(X))](BH) \\
&= [Dv(u(z(X)))] (2z(X)C(BH)^T) \\
&= 2u(z(X))):(2z(X)C(BH)^T)^T \\
&= 4u(BX):(BXC(BH)^T)^T \\
&= 4[BXC(BX)^T]:(BXC(BH)^T)^T \\
&= 4[BXC(BX)^T]:[BHCX^TB^T] \\
&= 4[B^TBXC(BX)^T]:[HCX^TB^T] \\
&= 4[B^TBXC(BX)^T(CX^TB^T)^T]:H \\
&= 4[B^TBXCX^TB^TBXC]:H
\end{align}$$
In particular, for $B=I$ you get
$$Df(X)(H) = 4[XCX^TXC]:H$$

Notice that what the matrix cookbook actually says is
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\mathrm{tr}(X^TCXX^TCX) = 4CXX^TCX$$
but the left hand side is $(\partial/\partial X)f(X^T)$, so it's not exactly what you have.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the gradient of $f$ is wrong and it should be
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
= 4(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{X}^T)\mathbf{X}\mathbf{C}
$$
Now let $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{BX}$, so that your new function writes
$g(\mathbf{X})=f(\mathbf{Y})$.

Using this fact, it follows (using the same notations as Greg) that the differential of $g$ writes
\begin{eqnarray*}
dg
&=&4(\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{Y}^T)\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{C}:d\mathbf{Y} \\
&=&4\mathbf{B}^T(\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{Y}^T)\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{C}:d\mathbf{X} 
\end{eqnarray*}
so the gradient of $g$ is $4\mathbf{B}^T(\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{Y}^T)\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{C}$

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\Pi{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}}
\def\Pj{\prod_{j=k+1}^{n}}
\def\Pk{\prod_{k=\ell}^{m}}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=1}^{n}}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Consider a matrix product $(P)$ constructed
from individual `quadratic` factors
$$\eqalign{
&Q_k = B_kXC_kX^TB_k^T
  \qiq dQ_k = B_k\LR{dX\:C_kX^T + XC_k\:dX^T}B_k^T \\
&P_{(\ell,\,m)} = {\Pk Q_k } \;=\; Q_\ell\cdot Q_{\ell+1}\cdot Q_{\ell+2}\,\cdots\, Q_m \\
&P = P_{(\o,\,n)} \\
}$$
with the convention that the partial product
$\,P_{(\ell,\,m)}\,$ is the identity matrix when $\,\ell>m\,$

and the $\{Q_k,C_k\}$ matrices are symmetric.

It will also be convenient to define the partial sums
$$ F_k = P_{(\o,\,k-\o)} \qquad G_k = P_{(k+\o,\,n)} $$
so that, for any $\o\le k\le n$
$$ P = F_k\; Q_k\; G_k \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad $$

The differential of $P$ can be written as
$$\eqalign{
dP &= \Sk F_k\; dQ_k\; G_k \\
 &= \Sk F_k\,B_k\BR{dX\:C_kX^T + XC_k\:dX^T}B_k^T G_k \\
}$$

For typing convenience, introduce the Frobenius product with the properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
M:\LR{AB} &= \LR{MB^T}:A \;=\; \LR{A^TM}:B \\
I:B &= B:I \;=\; \trace{B} \\
}$$
The gradient of the product can be calculated as follows
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= I:P \\
d\phi &= I:dP \\
  &= I:\Sk{F_k\,
     B_k\BR{\c{dX}\:C_kX^T+XC_k\:\c{dX^T}}B_k^T G_k} \\
  &= \Sk B_k^TF^T_k\:\c{I}\;G^T_k\,B_kXC_k:dX
   \;+\; C_kX^TB_k^TF^T_k\:\c{I}\:
     G^T_kB_k:dX^T \\
 &= \LR{\Sk B_k^TF^T_kG^T_k\,B_kXC_k \;+\: B_k^TG_kF_kB_kXC_k}:dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X}
  &= {\Sk B_k^T\LR{F^T_kG^T_k \;+\: G_kF_k}B_kXC_k} \\
}$$
In the current problem, $\,n=2\,$ and the $\{B_k,\,C_k\}$ matrices are independent of $k,\:$ so the gradient expression is fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as $g(X)=BX\in\mathcal M_{m,r}(\mathbb R)$, you'll have
$$\text{trace}(BXCX^\top B^\top BXCX^\top B^\top)=\text{trace}(BXC(BX)^\top BXC(BX)^\top)=\text{trace}(g(X)Cg(X)^\top g(X)Cg(X)^\top)$$
I guess you can continue from here.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Actually, I had an idea like what you mentioned. But the problem is how can we deal with g(X)=BX?

Comment: @Math-Data: $g'(X)=B$ and an operator on $Mat(r\times r')$